# Any ressources of methodologies to study sequences such as $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ and $u_{n+1}=u_{n}^2+v_{n}^2$ with exercises?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I have a rigorous analysis class that concentrates on sequences, partial sums, harmonic sums, series and similar. As I am preparing for my exams, I would love to practice as much as possible my weak points, which are sequences of such types : $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ and something along $u_{n+1}=u_{n}^2+v_{n}^2$ (basically a sequence defined from two other sequences). I would like to ask do you have any good ressources online that would show basic methodologies, interesting cases of the study of such sequences, and then that would have a lot ( and I mean a lot) of exercises concerning such type of sequences?

Any indication will be appreciated. If you believes this question doesn't belong on MSE feel free to flag it to the moderators.